# Why doesn't work button that increases the number (simulation of likes)? How to fix this problem?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a button that increases the number of right by 1 (simulation of likes). Also I want to create this with only one component. But for some reason, the code doesn't work. How to fix this problem?

```
class Like extends React.Component {
  state = {
    like: 0,
  }

  plus() {
    this.setState({
      like: this.state.like + 1,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.plus}>click me</button>
        {this.state.like}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Like />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vt2rwyse/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the `plus()` function, the `this` keyword is undefined. You need to bind it to your component so that it points to the right context. Or you can use an arrow-function, which has lexical-binding.

```
class Like extends React.Component {
  state = {
    like: 0,
  }

  plus = () => {
    this.setState({
      like: this.state.like + 1,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.plus}>click me</button>
        {this.state.like}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Like />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
class Like extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        like: 0
     }
     this.plus = this.plus.bind(this)
  }

  plus() {
    this.setState({
      like: this.state.like + 1,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.plus}>click me</button>
        {this.state.like}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Like />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Also, there should be 
this.setState(prev=>({
      like: prev.like + 1
    }));